# rewrite for single PHP file

Tags: 8, .htaccess

I'm asking in this forum because there are some specific Drupal 8 rules that might need to be applied.

I am looking for the correct way to add .htaccess rules that allow for:

`domain.com/specific/`  to be `domain.com/script.php`

I would first have to allow the request for `/specific/` to happen without Drupal taking it, and then point `/specific/` to `/script.php`

The closest I have been able to get is:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/specific/"
  RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

  RewriteRule ^specific(/|$) script.php [L]
```

This is not ideal though, as the user ends up at:   `domain.com/script.php`

Comment: What do you have so far? Does it work? Or doesn't it?

Comment: @leymannx I've updated wiht as close as I've been able to figure out so far.

Comment: Use `/specific/index.php` for your script file, no rewrite rule should be needed for this to be accessible with plain `/specific`

Comment: @hudri for various reasons, `script.php` needs to stay in the root level.